# Is it possible to tell if an incoming connection is using an SQL Server Alias?

Tags: sql-server, alias

Using SQL Server Configuration Manager to [Create a Server Alias for Use by a Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-2014) is cool tool used in many cases [when it works](https://sqlstudies.com/2014/06/18/aliasing-a-sql-server-when-it-works-when-it-doesnt-and-when-it-may-be-your-problem/)

In my DBA position I do not have access to the application server, to see if the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017) or the [SQL Server Client Network Utility *(not sure this is the correct link)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/client-network-configuration?view=sql-server-2017) was used to create an alias.

Is there any way I can use SSMS, or any logs, events, etc to identify that an incoming connection is connecting with an Alias?

Comment: @McNets Even at the audit level, it's already too late, the alias has been translated by the client before the connection is ever established, and the client doesn't tell the audit anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that translation is done on the client side and so, with or without an alias, those connections are going to look the same to SQL Server. There is no evidence in DMVs like `sys.dm_exec_connections` or `sys.dm_exec_sessions` what name/IP/port combination was entered by the user to resolve to the server where SQL Server is running. SQL Server itself only cares that the connection was established.

Unless you can infer that anyone *not* using an alias is using shared memory or named pipes, therefore anyone using TCP must be using an alias. I can assure you that this is not a safe assumption.